# How to notify users when record is updated by another user (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

When multiples users are updating the same record at that time how to notify other users that someone has updated the record recently.


So is there any provision that other user will get the updated copy of the record or will get the instant notification?

Comment: Maybe a trigger on the table and column and sending e mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you come to know that record is already updated. You should use optimistic locking for this. When you have implemented optimistic locking. When you will try to update the record which is already updated. It will throw concurrency error. That you can display on UI with proper message. This record is already updated Please refresh the page and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web application where instant notification will show. SignalR Javascript library handle it with asp.net using SQL Dependency.